# Removing files from folders in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I am removing a certain file from many folders. But when that file is missing in a folder, it runs into an error. Basically, I want the code to scan every folder, see if the file exists there and delete it. If there is no file in a specific folder, it should skip that since there is nothing to delete and move to the next folder.

```
import os
N = [i+1 for i in range(101)]
I=[]

for i in N:
    if i in I:
        continue
    os.remove(rf"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\220 nodes_seed75_var1_1000stepsize_0.4initial_K_1e3\{i}\Indices.txt")
```

The error is

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: What is `I` supposed to be?

Comment: Use `if os.isfile(filename)` to check if the file exists. Or put `try/except` around the call to `os.remove()` so you can ignore the error.

Comment: Why don't you catch the exception and ignore it and continue to the next iteration?

Comment: BTW `[i+1 for i in range(101)]` can be simplified to `list(range(1, 102))`. You don't need to add 1 if you start the range at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has instructions called `try / except` allowing you to perform an action that could raise an exception, catch this exception if it *is* raised, and act consequently.

Some documentation about these instructions can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

I simply added it to your code for you to see an example: the script now tries to remove the file. If it cannot do it because the file does not exist, then it will raise a `FileNotFoundError` that will be catched by the `except` block, where it prints something.

```py
import os
import sys
N = [i+1 for i in range(101)]
I=[]

for i in N:
    if i in I:
        continue
    try:
        os.remove(rf"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\220 nodes_seed75_var1_1000stepsize_0.4initial_K_1e3\{i}\Indices.txt")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File does not exist inside of {i} folder.", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: But it doesn't tell me folder numbers where the file doesn't exist...how can i get the specific folder numbers?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The code I sent was just an example. Let me edit it to add the info.